# How can 2 or more instances of the same program to communicate in local network?

Tags: networking, php, perl, ruby, sockets

I want to create program which will be in use for few computers connected in local network. Basically the program aim is to keep track of all tables in a bar ( lets say ), which are reserved.

When some user book a table as reserved the program should broadcast the table number to all other Pc's and mark the table as reserved. Since all computers use the same program, how is possible to create communication between all of them ?

Should i use sockets to achieve this? If it matters, all of the computers have installed Linux OS,and the app will be developed in ruby,perl or php.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Linux, there is a standard solution to that problem: a named pipe. A named pipe is a file to which one process writes, and from which another process reads as soon as the data become available. The operating system takes care of waking up the reading process, and tell it "there are news for you". It also takes care of delivering to the istening process the exact amount of data that has become available, not more, not less. In other words, there might be 1 reservation, or 57 reservations, they will all be delivered correctly without your having to count for them.

You make a named pipe by means of the command:

```
mkfifo my_pipe
```

Now you use the file my_pipe like any other file, you can write to it, read from it, redirect to it, append to it:

```
echo "This is my name" > my_pipe

grep name my_pipe

cat my_pipe | while read; do ...; done
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: TCP/IP allows you to have a server/client relationship with ease.  The server could be at, for example, 192.168.0.1 and all the clients connect to that server.

Details:
If you have a mysql database or equivalent you can have all the computers contact the single database to store the reservation data.  If you make it web based you can create a web page to run from an apache server with php.  Then you can launch a web browser on all the client PC's and have each client refresh the page once a minute.  Given this solution use apache web server the graphical user interface can look any way you want it to look.  All the client PC's would simple launch a web browser and point to http:///tables (or whatever)

Another option create a google account and then create a calendar for each table.  Google has free and publicly available php api (and several other languages) that you can use to add/manage events to the google calendar.  If you need to make any read-only you can create a second google account and do a read-only share to the second account. You can display the read only or read/write account in the web browser at each table.  You can turn all the calendars on or just display the calendar for that table.
(I do something similiar with google calendar for room scheduling)